# Get out-of-date instances within AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-code-deploy

I'm looking for a way to get a list of out-of-date instances for an application deployment group, I've been looking in to using the JavaScriptSDK but can't seem to find a call that will list the instances.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodeDeploy.html

All I can seem to find is a way to update out of instances by setting the `updateOutdatedInstancesOnly` flag when calling `createDeployment` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodeDeploy.html#createDeployment-property

Does anyone know if it's possible to just get a list of out of date instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not an easy way to answer that question exactly with the existing APIs. You configure EC2 tags and AutoScaling Groups in your deployment group, so there are no hard associations between a DG and a host, and the list of hosts in a given deployment group are created dynamically when you create a deployment.

However, if answering the question "What hosts failed in the last deployment?" gets you want you need, there is a way to get that information.

1. Call `listDeploymentInstances` repeatedly until you get all of the instance IDs.
2. Call `batchGetDeploymentInstances` repeatedly until you get all of the hosts and check the status of each host to find the failed ones.

That should at least get information regarding the last deployment.

Comment: I was expecting that might be the answer but was hoping there might be some magic call on their api that wasn't exposed on the sdk. It's not the instances that are failed, we have the hooks removed from our AutoScaling Group so if we scale out we don't kick off the code deploy. so I want to query which ones that have not been deployed yet. However, your workaround will work for this instance too!